# How to get food in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

**How can I gather (proper) food in the Nether?** By "proper", I mean  any food excepting Rotten Flesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of mushrooms in the nether, shown below:

[image: Mushrooms in the nether]

You can bring some wood to make bowls, and make mushroom soup.(If you don't know, you need one bowl, one red mushroom, and one brown mushroom for mushroom soup.)